# Al insertar un array en Sql Server el Id asignado desordena el array

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Perdón por el título pero no sabía como describir la situación.
La situación es la siguiente: tengo un proyecto en VS2017, asp.net core en donde tengo un método que ingresa un array a la base de datos. Es un array de una tabla que creo con Jquery que es un plan de pagos de la deuda de un cliente.

VIEW

```
<script>
    $("#boton").click(function () {
        var filas = $("#cuotas").val();
        var monto = $("#montocuota").val();
        var dni = $("#dni").val();
        var fecha = $("#fechavto").val();
        var tabla = "";
        var result = $("#tablaplan");
        tabla += "<table class=table table-hover>";
        tabla += "<thead>";
        tabla += "<tr>";
        tabla += "<th>Cuota N°</th>";
        tabla += "<th>Monto</th>";
        tabla += "<th>Fecha Vto</th>";
        tabla += "<th>Documento</th>";
        tabla += "</tr>";
        tabla += "</thead>";
        tabla += "<tbody>";
        for (var i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            var vto = moment(fecha).add((i), 'month').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            tabla += "<tr>";
            tabla += "<td>" + "<input name=[" + i + "].Cuota value=" + (i + 1) + " class=form-control input-sm readonly style=width:100px></input>" + "</td>";
            tabla += "<td>" + "<input name=[" + i + "].Monto_cuota value=" + monto + " class=form-control input-sm readonly style=width:100px></input>" + "</td>";
            tabla += "<td>" + "<input name=[" + i + "].Fecha_vto value=" + vto + " class=form-control input-sm readonly style=width:150px></input>" + "</td>";
            tabla += "<td>" + "<input name=[" + i + "].Dni value=" + dni + " class=form-control input-sm readonly style=width:150px></input>" + "</td>";
            tabla += "<td>" + "<input name=[" + i + "].Estado value=Activo class=form-control input-sm readonly style=width:150px type=hidden></input>" + "</td>";
            tabla += "</tr>";
        }

        tabla += "</tbody>";
        tabla += "</table>";
        result.html(tabla);
    });

</script>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Fecha,Cuotas,MontoCuota,Estado,Dni,Total")] PlanPagos planPagos, string Dni, ICollection<DetallePlanPagos> detallePlanPagos)
            {

//verifico si tiene plan activo               
var query = from d in _context.Deudores
            join p in _context.PlanesPagos on d.Dni equals p.Dni
            where p.Estado == "Activo" && p.Dni == Convert.ToInt32(Dni)
            select p;
var cuenta = query.Count();

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    if (cuenta == 0)
                    {

                        _context.DetallesPlanesPagos.AddRange(detallePlanPagos);
                        _context.Add(planPagos);
                        foreach(var item in detallePlanPagos)
                        {
                            //asigno FK
                            item.PlanPagosId = planPagos.Id;
                        }
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        return View("Success");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewData["mensaje"] = string.Format("Error!. El deudor con Dni {0} ya" +
                            " tiene una refinanciación activa. Deberá anularla para cargar otro Plan de Pagos.", Dni);
                        return View("ErrorAlProcesar", ViewData["mensaje"]);
                    }

                }
                return View(planPagos);
            }
```

Si bien todo funciona bien, el problema surje en que por ejemplo, en que si pongo muchas cuotas, mas de 15 en la base de datos me los inserta de esta forma (captura de pantalla de la tabla en la base de datos):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar el Id esta perfecto, pero el orden de la cuota esta desordenado. De la cuota número 1 pasa a la 17 en vez de a la cuota número 2.
En otros caso donde ingreso un plan de pagos de, por ejemplo, 5 cuotas, no tengo ningún problema.

Alguna sugerencia?
Muchas gracias

Comment: y si los ordenas al recuperar la info?

Comment: Esto es un grave error de concepto. Los datos en las bases de datos no estan ordenados. Se ordenan al pedirlos (al hacer el select) con un order by. Ninguna base de datos asegura ningun orden a menos que apliques esa clausula y ninguna db asegura que un select sin order devuelva siempre los registros en el mismo orden.

Comment: Si entiendo. En el select lo puedo ordenar y que me muestre en forma ordenada por el campo `Cuota`, eso esta claro. El problema que me surje es que al momento de cancelar una cuota siempre lo hace buscando la primera cuota que no esta cancelada. Siguiendo este orden en la base de datos, primero va a cancelar la cuota n°1 y luego la cuota n° 17. Se entiende?.

Comment: Ya lo solucione. Antes de insertar ordeno por numero de cuota. Por lo que se va cancelando por orden de cuota en el correcto orden.
Saludos y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione. Antes de insertar ordeno por numero de cuota. Por lo que se va cancelando por orden de cuota en el correcto orden.
Saludos y gracias.
Agrego el código que hizo que funcionara:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Recibo creado por Usuario: {ID}.", User.Identity.Name);
_context.Add(recibo);


//agrego Id al recibo                            
var detalleId = _context.DetallesPlanesPagos.Where(o => o.Dni.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(Dni)) && o.NRecibo == 0).OrderBy(x => x.Cuota).FirstOrDefault();
recibo.DetallePlanPagosId = detalleId.Id;

//guardo cambios
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
await ActDetallePago(Convert.ToInt32(Dni));
return View("Success");
```